# django rest framework check if serializer received None object

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Our endpoint can return from multiple models, all have something in common so they are mapped to an uniform response, e.g.:

```
{
"reference": "November15-Inbound-1",
"note": null,
"inbound_date": "2018-11-14",
"inbound_lines": [
    {
        "article_code": "VBP_A",
        "quantity": 1
    }
]
```

}

Now it is possible that when doing a retrieve or update call that the object does not exist:

```
try:
    return AppInbound.objects.filter(customer__code=self.customer.code).get(**kwargs)
except AppInbound.DoesNotExist:
    return None
```

This 'None' is then returned to our serializer, which yields the following result:

```
{
    "reference": "",
    "note": "",
    "inbound_date": null,
    "inbound_lines": []
}
```

Is there a way I can check whether or not the serializer received a None object as input? Without having to do specific code per endpoint like:

```
if serialized_data['reference'] == "":
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override `get_initial()` in your serializer and check whether the instance is `None`. This method is responsible for returning the initial state of each field.

```
def get_initial(self):
    if self.instance is None:
        raise Http404
    return super().get_initial()
```